# Scala - How to filter KStream (Kafka Streams)

Tags: java, scala, filter, apache-kafka-streams

I'm new on Scala and I'm trying to filter a KStream[String, JsonNode] based on the second component fields.

As a example, the working Java code is this:

```java
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced;
...
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
...
...
final KStream<String, JsonNode> source = streamsBuilder.stream(inputTopic,
                    Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde));


// filter and producer preprocessed
source.filter((k, v) -> v.get("total_cost").asDouble() > 0 && v.get("num_items").asInt() > 0)
    .to(outputTopic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde));
```

I have tried this:

```scala
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.{Produced,Consumed,KStream};
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
...
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
...
var source:KStream[String, JsonNode] = streamsBuilder.stream(inputTopic, Consumed.`with`(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde));

source.filter({
  case (k:String ,v:JsonNode) => 
    (v.get("total_cost").asDouble() > 0 && v.get("num_items").asInt() > 0)
  })
  .to(outputTopic, Produced.`with`(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde));
```

In the above try i got:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type missing parameter type for
>   expanded function The argument types of an anonymous function must be
>   fully known. (SLS 8.5) Expected type was:
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Predicate[? >: String, ? >:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode]

I also tried this:

```scala
source.filter((_._2.get("total_cost").asDouble() > 0 && _._2.get("num_items").asInt() > 0))
  .to(outputTopic, Produced.`with`(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde));
```

How could i filter this object in Scala?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kafka Streams offers a first class Scala API. Check out the docs on how to use it: https://kafka.apache.org/24/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#scala-dsl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Predicate` comes from JavaAPI, in Scala `2.11` (I assume you use it) you have to implement interface explicitly, thus:

```
source.filter(new Predicate[String, JsonNode]() {
  override def test(k: String, v: JsonNode): Boolean = {
    v.get("total_cost").asDouble() > 0 && v.get("num_items").asInt() > 0
  }
}).to(outputTopic, Produced.`with`(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde));
```

should work.

More on `SAM`s (Single Abstract Methods) can be found [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#lambda-syntax-for-sam-types)

Note that you don't have to use Java API - there is first-class [Scala API](https://kafka.apache.org/24/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#scala-dsl).

Comment: Kafka Streams offers a first class Scala API. Thus, there should be no need to use the Java `Predicate` class. Cf. https://kafka.apache.org/24/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#scala-dsl

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax thanks for suggestion, I've edited the answer

Comment: I'm very new in Scala, could you provide also and example using the scala API?

Comment: hint: use org.apache.kafka.streams.scala._ package